# How would I go about determining whether the subset of polynomials for which p(-1) = p(0) = p(5) is a subspace of the vector space of all polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I'm aware of the 3 conditions a subset must meet in order for it to be a subspace of the vector space, but I have no idea how to apply them to this particular question, nor to polynomial vector spaces in general.

Comment: You just check  the set is non empty (e.g. it contains $x(x+1)(x-5)$), and stable by addition & scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kernel of the linear map $\Bbb R[X]\to \Bbb R^2$, $p\mapsto (p(-1)-p(0),p(5)-p(0))$. $\square$